# Robots interpreting script tags

Tags: web-applications, web-crawler, robots.txt

Our web application is currently crawled by a multitude of robots.
However, some of them seem to try and parse javascript tags and interpret some of it as links, which are called and fill our error log with loads of 404s.

On our pages we have tracking scripts like Google Analytics or Piwik, looking like this:

```
//the line below seems to be interpreted (1)
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '<account id>']);
    //the line below seems to be interpreted (2)
    _gaq.push(['_gat._anonymizeIp']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        //the line below seems to be interpreted (3)
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
</script>
```

Thus, when some robots crawl our site (let's say `mydomain.com/application/index.html`), we get requests for urls like those (depending on the robot):

- `mydomain.com/application/text/javascript` (1)
- `mydomain.com/application/_gat._anonymizeIp` (2)
- `mydomain.com/application/('https:` (3)

I can't tell for sure that all the lines above are interpreted or if others are, but some parts (e.g. the `_gat._anonymizeIp`) only appear once in the page source and thus it's quite likely that the robots take those "relative links" from those lines.

From the description of those robots they don't seem to be malicious and thus should adhere to directives like those in robots.txt etc.

However, AFAIK one can only allow/disallow entire pages using robots.txt or the meta tag. Is this correct or is there some way to exclude parts of a page from crawling?

If not, what might be done to prevent standard robots from interpreting those scripts?

As a side note: there seem to be several independent robots, so dealing with every single one would not be an option. Besides that, our customers would not want some of those robots to be excluded entirely.

**Addiontional information**:

It seems like all robots' operators state that their robot obeys robots.txt (I didn't check them all).

Additionally, not *every* string literal seems interpreted (e.g. there are no `.../_trackPageview` requests).

Also, some of those robots seem to look for the same sort of information (job offerings in that case) and thus there might be some common source code.

So what I suspect would be a some error in the parser that doesn't recognize script tags or doesn't parse them correctly.

Thus, we tried to wrap the scripts in old-style comments (`<!-- ... //-->`), which might cause the robots to ignore the entire script. Using those comments should be safe here, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Robots.txt can only block an entire page. There is no way to block just part of the page.

You could try moving the JavaScript to a file, and then use robots.txt to block just the JavaScript file. If the robot really does obey robots.txt, this might work.

My guess is that the robot probably does not obey robots.txt. Only polite, well-behaved robots obey robots.txt. Interpreting every single string literal in the JS as a URL is not what I'd call polite behavior. If robots.txt is not supported, you will have to either block each robot by IP, or just put up with the 404 errors.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I'll look into that. The robot's operators state that they obey robots.txt and from their reputation I'd guess they tell the truth. I'll add that to my question.